# Google Sheet: How to define the "cols.label" value in JSON export?

Tags: json, google-sheets

I use a google sheet as an endpoint to import data into an html table. Depending on the type of data in the sheet I get a different JSON structure.

To explain the problem, I built a Google sheet with two very simple tables.
The only difference between the two tables is the Age field which is numeric in Sheet1 and textual in Sheet2.

[image]

[Link document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13roZPcYwPQU-bczEkd6XLMZmeqEayN6tO6JPrzXUJ5w/edit#gid=0)

If I use sheets as JSON endpont I get this behavior: Sheet1 exports the header correctly, but Sheet2 shows an empty header (column headers become normal row values).

**Sheet1 JSON**

```
{
    "version": "0.6",
    "reqId": "0",
    "status": "ok",
    "sig": "325167901",
    "table": {
        "cols": [
            {
                "id": "A",
                "label": "Name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "id": "B",
                "label": "Age",
                "type": "number",
                "pattern": "General"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "Vittorio"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 52.0,
                        "f": "52"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "parsedNumHeaders": 1
    }
}
```

**Sheet2 JSON**

```
{
    "version": "0.6",
    "reqId": "0",
    "status": "ok",
    "sig": "1566616543",
    "table": {
        "cols": [
            {
                "id": "A",
                "label": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "id": "B",
                "label": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "Name"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": "Age"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "Vittorio"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": "52"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "parsedNumHeaders": 0
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix Sheet2 behavior?

Comment: In your situation, I thought that a simple method is to modify the Spreadsheet like the clean-up of the number format. But, I'm not sure about the detail of your goal. So, I have a question. Do you want to achieve your goal by modifying the Spreadsheet? Or, do you want to achieve your goal without modifying the Spreadsheet? If you select 1st one, what language do you want to use?

Comment: Which methods are you using to obtain those JSONs?

Comment: Strange, after some tests, I can't find a solution. Even though the first line is present in the json as a line, there seems to be a bug. I suggest you to put an issue in the google issue tracker

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I reply a little late.
I use the sheets to show data on a web page that I am designing, but the problem is not the import of the data, it is the variable format of the JSON.

I get the JSON through fetct (url). These are the links to download the two tables in JSON format.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13roZPcYwPQU-bczEkd6XLMZmeqEayN6tO6JPrzXUJ5w/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=0

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13roZPcYwPQU-bczEkd6XLMZmeqEayN6tO6JPrzXUJ5w/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=1574520586

Comment: can you provide the piece of code in which you transform json into your html table, so that we could adapte to the case without labels. however I have posted an answer with a way to detect if labeles are present or not

Comment: My goal is to get a well formatted html table from google sheets. Gogle Sheets are compiled by users and I'm not sure if they comply with the correct formats. Sometimes I might have a correct header, sometimes not.

A possible solution is to use the JSON value "parsedNumHeaders" which takes the value 0 or 1 depending on the case.

Unfortunately I am in the mountains, in a few days I will send my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a problem, meanwhile what I suggest is to test the JSON endpont labels as follows

```
const jsonString = `/*O_o*/
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"1566616543","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Name"},{"v":"Age"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Vittorio"},{"v":"52"}]}],"parsedNumHeaders":0}});`

function jsonWithLabels(jsonString) {
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString.slice(47,-2))
  var labels = json.table.cols.map(c => c.label)
  return (labels.join('') != '')
}

function test(){
  console.log (jsonWithLabels(jsonString))
}
```

if false, you need to fetch the labels from row 1

```js
const jsonString = `/*O_o*/
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"1566616543","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Name"},{"v":"Age"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Vittorio"},{"v":"52"}]}],"parsedNumHeaders":0}});`

  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString.slice(47,-2))
  var labels = json.table.cols.map(c => c.label)
  console.log (labels.join('') != '')
```

here is a complete script to rebuild the table with and without labels

```js
const jsonString = `/*O_o*/
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"1566616543","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Name"},{"v":"Age"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Vittorio"},{"v":"52"}]}],"parsedNumHeaders":0}});`
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = myItems(jsonString.slice(47, -2))

  function myItems(jsonString) {
    var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    var table = '<table>';
    var flag = jsonWithLabels(json);
    if (flag) {
      table += '<tr>';
      json.table.cols.forEach(colonne => table += '<th>' + colonne.label + '</th>')
      table += '</tr>';
    }
    json.table.rows.forEach((row, index) => {
      table += '<tr>';
      row.c.forEach(cel => {
        try { var valeur = cel.f ? cel.f : cel.v }
        catch (e) { var valeur = '' }
        if (!flag && index == 0) { table += '<th>' + valeur + '</th>' }
        else { table += '<td>' + valeur + '</td>' }
      })
      table += '</tr>';
    })
    table += '</table>';
    return table
  }
  function jsonWithLabels(json) {
    var labels = json.table.cols.map(c => c.label);
    return (labels.join('') != '')
  }
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
th,td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div id="json">json here</div>
```

Comment: Good idea! Thanks for the complete code.
I found another possible solution using the value of "parsedNumHeaders" as a test.
"parsedNumHeaders": 1 in the first table
"parsedNumHeaders": 0 in the second table